# Task cannot access environment file stored in an Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I have created an ECS cluster, with a task definition and a service from that task definition. As you can see in the following image, I have added an environment file to the container definition (stored in Amazon S3):

[image]

That file is private, so I have to add some policies to the task role and the task execution role (I'm using the same role for both cases because I do not have the distinction between them very clear yet). Here you can see the task definition assigned roles:

[image]

That role has the following policies added to it:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::badger-next"
        }
    ]
}
```

And:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Even though that's done, I'm still seeing this error when the service tries to boot up new instances:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: To give permissions to objects inside of a bucket and not the bucket itself, you need to use `arn:aws:s3:::badger-next/*`

Comment: I have tried and does not work. I have even tried with "*", but the same result.